# Micronaut liveness always unknown

Tags: micronaut, kubernetes-health-check

I'm currently trying to add `liveness` and `readiness` endpoints to my service to deploy it on k8s.

I'm using the latest micronaut release (2.5.4), and having the following setup:

application.yml:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: sandbox

endpoints:
  health:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
    details-visible: ANONYMOUS
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.32"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.4.32"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.0.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.5.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.4.32"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.example"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.example.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-management")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.ApplicationKt")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }


}
```

Whenever I'm hitting the endpoint `localhost:8080/health/liveness` the response I'm getting is:

```
{"name":"sandbox","status":"UNKNOWN"}
```

However, when I'm calling `localhost:8080/health/readiness` I'm getting correct response:

```
{"name":"sandbox","status":"UP","details":{"compositeDiscoveryClient()":{"name":"sandbox","status":"UP"},"diskSpace":{"name":"sandbox","status":"UP","details":{"total":499963174912,"free":384382533632,"threshold":10485760}},"service":{"name":"sandbox","status":"UP"}}}
```

It seems that I'm missing something but I couldn't find anything in Micronaut documentation about this...

Comment: Do you have any beans in your context that are marked with `@Liveness`?

Comment: right now I don't but when I did it still had the same result, just with a section inside it that was unknown as well (I've mimicked the Cassandra liveness class)

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  If you can reproduce it in a sample app, please file an issue at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues and we can investigate.  A `@Liveness` bean like https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/b6c881f92e142878e4b4aaee3be2fcc5 should work.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Works like a charm - I misunderstood the usage of `@Liveness` and expected it to work as `@Singleton` as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great.  I am glad that you got it worked out.  Let us know if we can be of any help!

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown, glad that you've showed the way to do it. Would you be so kind and provide an answer to this question for better visibility for other community members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help in the comments, I've managed to solve the issue.

To make the `liveness` work you need to add a Liveness implementation in form similar to the following:

```
@Singleton
@Liveness
class LivenessIndicator : HealthIndicator {
    override fun getResult(): Publisher<HealthResult> =
        Flowable.just(HealthResult.builder(LIVENESS_NAME).status(HealthStatus.UP).build())

    companion object {
        private const val LIVENESS_NAME = "liveness"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The current accepted answer will not report a status that reflects the real application status since you enforce your application to always return `UP` no matter what error occurs within it.

The proper setup that should work is für your `application.yaml`:

```
endpoints:
  all:
    # Expose all management endpoints on a different port. This allows us to control access
    port: 8081
    sensitive: false
  info:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
  health:
    details-visible: ANONYMOUS
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
```

and your k8s `deployment` should be set properly e.g.

```
      ports:
        - name: management
          containerPort: 8081
          protocol: TCP
      livenessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 3
        httpGet:
          path: /health
          port: 8081
        initialDelaySeconds: 50
      readinessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 3
        httpGet:
          path: /info
          port: 8081
        initialDelaySeconds: 15
```

If this is not working, check your network policies